# EF Core 5: Dependences between models

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have 2 models as follows, Location and Nominal. Nominals have a foreign key for Location, and Location can have a number of  different default Nominals for different purposes.

```
public class Nominal
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string NominalCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public char Analysis { get; set; }

    // link to location

    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }       

}
```

The location model looks like this;

```
public class Location : AutoTracking
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Nominal")]
    public Guid? DefaultNominal1Id { get; set; }
    public Nominal DefaultNominal1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Nominal")]
    public Guid? DefaultNominal2Id { get; set; }
    public Nominal DefaultNominal2 { get; set; }
}
```

Due to Nominal having a Location link already, the link back from Location to Nominal is generated an error. The suggested solution in the error is to add the [NotMapped] attribute to the navigation properties, which I've done.

Is there any side effect of adding the not mapped, I assume I'll still be able to load the navigation properties using EF core lazy loading?

Comment: Why are you assuming and not checking to see if you can load the navigation properties? Also, is there any specific reason for not using a one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your classes:

```
public partial class Nominal
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string NominalCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public char Analysis { get; set; }

    // link to location

    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(nameof(LocationId))]
    [InverseProperty("Nominals")]
    public virtual Location Location{ get; set; }

public partial class Location : AutoTracking
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Nominal.Location))]
     public virtual ICollection<Nominal> Nominals{ get; set; }
}
```

If for some reasons you need more properties you can add them this way:

```
public partial class Location : AutoTracking
{ 
 [NotMapped]
   public Guid? DefaultNominal1Id { get; set; }
 [NotMapped]
    public Nominal DefaultNominal1 { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Guid? DefaultNominal2Id { get; set; }
 [NotMapped]
    public Nominal DefaultNominal2 { get; set; 
}
```

But you can assign values to them only manualy.